# SSRS Report Query

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to insert a clickable `+` sign in an SSRS report column header? If "yes," then, on clicking that operator, I would like to display other columns which have been hidden by default. For example, as shown in the attached [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFO5r.png), to display columns 'AP' and 'CR' when sign `+` of column 'U' is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide a column and toggle the **Visibility** based on another column header.

Right Click on the **column** you want to hide (where the Red Dot is) and go to the Visibility property.

Click on the **Hide** radio button so the column is Hidden when the report is run.

Check the **Display can be Toggled** box and choose the name of your U column.

[image]

Resulting table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your quick reply ... I am able to implement above scenario in my test report... but when I try to implement in actual report "Column visibility" option is disabled... your inputs would be appreciated...

Comment: You'll probably need to edit your question and show the report design, are you using a matrix (with column groups)?

Comment: @ChintanDave - I tried but can't make a scenario where the column visibility is disabled (matrix, table in table...). Are you doing something funky with your table? A report design pic might help. Otherwise try creating a new table - sometimes it's easier to start over than figure out some weird bug.